# PHP - Custom sorting of a subset of data in an array

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I have an unusual problem.

I generate lists of car models (each list being an array). In most cases, sorting the list using `natcasesort()` is just fine, but in some cases subsets of the lists need to be sorted chronologically in a custom order rather than alphabetically.

What I need is to have a global function that every list is checked against and sorted accordingly. The part which stumps me is that I only need a subset of the list sorted, and every other element needs the standard `natcasesort()` applied.

I've written what I think are good foundations, but I am completely stuck at the sorting algorithm itself:

```
function customSort($arr){
    $groups=array(
        // My custom sort groups, in desired final sort order
        array('Porsche 911 (964/965)','Porsche 911 (993)','Porsche 911 (996)','Porsche 911 (997)','Porsche 911 (991)'),
        array('BMW M2','BMW 3 Series','BMW M3','BMW 4 Series','BMW M4','BMW 5 Series','BMW M5','BMW 6 Series','BMW M6')
    );
    foreach($groups as $v){
        // If match is found, sort and return array
        if(count(array_intersect($arr,$v))>0){
            usort($arr,'runSort');
            return $arr;
        }
    }
    // If match not found, run and return standard sort
    natcasesort($arr);
    return $arr;
}

function runSort($a,$b){
    // ???
}

$oldarray=array('AAA','Porsche 911 (993)','ZZZ','Porsche 911 (991)','Porsche 911 (997)','hhh');
$newarray=customSort($oldarray);
```

Doing a `print_r` on `$newarray` should return:

```
> AAA
> hhh
> Porsche 911 (993)
> Porsche 911 (997)
> Porsche 911 (991)
> ZZZ
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Just a pointer - you're returning inside your `foreach` loop. What are you expecting to happen if I pass an array containing both a Porsche and a BMW?

Comment: @WarrenSergent-spakatak.com: Won't happen - the site only passes arrays containing related elements to the function. The return is equivalent to a break in this case.

Comment: No problems - the generic 'AAA', 'hhh', etc made that less obvious.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that - thanks for asking. The generic terms were included just to demonstrate that the initial array may contain terms not referenced in the custom arrays, and in these cases they should be sorted alongside regardless (this is the part I am struggling with!).